# IPod touch location services

Tags: ipod-touch

A box popped up that says "Turn on location services to allow weather to determine yor location".  There are two tabs underneath that say "settings" and "cancel".  Neither of the tabs work the box won't go away.  I can't get it to shut off.  It's just stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Do a hard restart:
Hold the home button (the round one at the bottom) and the sleep wake button (the one on the top or the right side of your device) for 15 seconds or till the apple logo shows up.
If it does not appear, try to check if the device is still on, then try again, if it's off hold the sleep wake button.